# bash execute command for X arguments at a time

Tags: bash, arguments, limit

I have a list of files stored in txt file.

```
./test7
./test4
./test1
./test5
./test6
./test10
./test8
./test2
./test9
./test3
```

I want to run a command on all those files but I want to sleep 1 second after each two files are processed, eg:

```
cp ./test1 test1-backup
cp ./test2 test2-backup
sleep 1
cp ./test3 test3-backup
cp ./test4 test4-backup
sleep 1
...
cp ./test9 test9-backup
cp ./test10 test10-backup
```

Is there a way to achieve this by bash script? I would like to parametrize the amount of commands executed by 1 iteration (calling sleep 1).
Also another problem is that real list of files has hundreds thousands of lines.

Comment: I think you are better off using tar and gzip to archive and backup these files.

Comment: If you are able to execute commands remotely, can you not tar/zip those files/directories and back them up? as glenn mentioned, this means you'd have to wait days until the script could possibly complete which is not a good idea especially over a remote connection. If you do decide to go that route, you might want to consider doing it in batches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're not describing your real-world scenario: not only do you want to copy hundreds of thousands of files, but you want to sleep for hundreds of thousands of seconds... wtf?!?

Anyway:

```
while IFS= read -r file1
      IFS= read -r file2
do
    cp "$file1" "${file1##*/}-backup"
    cp "$file2" "${file2##*/}-backup"
    sleep 1
done < inputFile
```

Comment: It is a real world scenario. Iam performing commands on remote filesystem which is very fragile to those operations, eg. copying or removing. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @glenn jackman, you just beat me to the answer ;)

Comment: +1 but i'd also recommend to do this directly on the remote system using its crontab (if any) or another kind of robust session (screen?). not through a ssh session (or, if through ssh, via a "screen" session, if available on the remote host). ie, anything that will survive a disconnection

Comment: Cool! +1 One question: why note `"$file-backup"`?

Comment: According to the question, the destination file should not have a directory in the filename.

Comment: @glennjackman, ok, thank you; It is not explicit but it makes sense, according to the example.

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry**: I have not noticed the "txt file" with the "hundreds thousands of lines". This is just a naif solution...

```
for a in test*; do ls -l $a; if [[ $((i++ % 2)) != 0 ]]; then sleep 1; fi; done
```

**Update**: Explanation and (partially update to txt file with filenames).

...reformating:

```
for a in `cat file.txt`
do 
   cp "$a" "$a-backup"              ## REPLACE THIS LINE 
   if [[ $((i++ % 2)) != 0 ]] then
       sleep 1
   fi
done
```

- this one-liner means; `for a in files`  process the file $a and sleep if it is a even line.

In order to see if the line is even, we are counting  it (`i++`) and seeing if `i % 2 is 0`

- in bash `$(( ...exp ))` calculates `...exp` as numerical expression
- this way `$((i++ % 2)) != 0` will be true for even iterations (and in this
  case we `sleep 1`)
- in bash `[[ ...exp ]]` calculates `...exp` as a boolean expression

Note: this solution worked with a `file.txt` containing 100_000 files but it will fail for very big `file.txt`

Comment: Hi! This answer would probably be much more helpful if you explained how it is meant to work, and what placeholders are supposed to be replaced.

Comment: @dhag, thank you for the comment. Let's do it!

Comment: Do not use a for-loop to iterate over the lines of a file: as soon as you encounter a filename with a space in it, `$a` will not contain the whole filename (unless you alter `$IFS`) -- further reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F001.How_can_I_read_a_file_.28data_stream.2C_variable.29_line-by-line_.28and.2For_field-by-field.29.3F